# Gnomesort only works for first two strings

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I need to implement a gnomesort to sort strings on how close they are to the string input. I measure this difference with the Levenshtein-algoritm.

The algoritm works fine but only with if I have two strings in the database. It then sorts it fine, but if there are more than two strings, it just prints them in the order they are in the database. I really can't find the problem

```
public static void retrieveFromDatabase(String string) 
{        
    String[] sq = new String[database.size()];
    database.toArray(sq);        
    int r = 0, index = 1, y = 2, tmp1 = 0;
    String tmp2;

    int[] ds = new int[sq.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < database.size(); i++) {
        ds[i] = sortLevenshtein(string, database.get(i), false);
    }

    for(index = 1; index < ds.length; index++) // gnomsort
    {
        if(ds[index - 1] <= ds[index] )
        {
            ++index;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp1 = ds[index];
            tmp2 = sq[index];
            ds[index] = ds[index - 1];
            sq[index] = sq[index - 1];
            ds[index-1] = tmp1;
            sq[index-1] = tmp2;
            index--;
            if (index == 0) 
                index++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Best matches: ");
        for(r=0; r<Math.min(3,sq.length); r++)
        {
            System.out.println(ds[r] + "\t" + sq[r]);
        } 
}
```

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z41dW.png)

Comment: Gnomesort itself looks right. Perhaps you have some problems with strings (comparing, assigning etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gnome sort is not sorting correctly when there are more than two elements to sort.

In your problematic case your `ds` contains 1, 1, 0 from the outset. In your `for` loop `index` is 1. You see that the elements at indices 0 and 1 are in the correct order (both elements are 1), so you increment `index` to 2 in the `if` statement. Next your `for` loop also increments `index`, so it is now 3. 3 is not less than `ds.length` (also 3), so the loop terminates.

I don’t know gnome sort, so I can’t tell you the fix. What I can tell you is that manipulating your `for` loop control variable — `index` in your code — inside the `for` loop is the sure way to code that is hard to understand and very hard to find errors in. I never ever do that.

```
    for(index = 1; index < ds.length; index++) // OK: loop control variable is incremented here
    {
        if(ds[index - 1] <= ds[index] )
        {
            ++index; // No-no: incrementing loop control variable, dangerous
        }
        else
        {
            tmp1 = ds[index];
            tmp2 = sq[index];
            ds[index] = ds[index - 1];
            sq[index] = sq[index - 1];
            ds[index-1] = tmp1;
            sq[index-1] = tmp2;
            index--; // No-no: decrementing loop control variable, problematic
            if (index == 0) 
                index++; // No-no: incrementing loop control variable
        }
    }
```

Comment: yess that was the problem. Changed the for to a while and it works. Thanks man